# How can i launch my shopify app withoit this error

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Whenever I attempt to run the npm run dev command I get stuck after asking which store I would like to use to view my project in and with the info box showing underneath. After maybe 10-15 seconds of waiting, an empty error box appears.

I didn't have any issues a few months ago and I have tried many basic fixes such as clearing cache, deleting node modules / package.json and running npm install again, and recreating my app from scratch.

My npm-cache logs don't give any meaningful information either.

I didn't have any issues a few months ago and I have tried many basic fixes such as clearing cache, deleting node modules / package.json and running npm install again, and recreating my app from scratch.

Comment: Which cli version are you using?

Comment: Try to update your app and cli then check again

Comment: If you create a new repo and run this command, is it still present?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Github Repo for the Shopify CLI. You can raise an issue there and perhaps they can help you. Provide the detailed error messages you get, the version etc, and maybe your questions will be answered!